# Explanation of the formulas for sums $\sum nr^n$ and $\sum n^2 r^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I am studying series for an exam right now and there is an example in the book I am studying (unfortunately the book is specific to my university so I cannot give any link) where certain series' sums are calculated. At some point the following ones are calculated:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}=\frac54$$

and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{25}{16}$$

I do not understand the reason that extra $n$ (the multiplier in the front) squares everything. Also I have no clue what to do when I have say

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}$$

Do I cube everything? Is there a specific way to do it that I do not get? If there is some online paper, book chapter or whatever that could help me, please link me to it!

Comment: What you are looking for is derivation of series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = 1/(1-x)$. Take the derivative you'll get the extra $n$ you mention. Take the second derivative you get $n(n-1)$ (and not $n^2$ but you can find the result with the two previous ones). You need some theory to do that (radius of convergence etc...) but that's roughly the idea

Comment: @BertrandR any specific page or paper with examples you could direct me to? I know some theory is missing from the book and probably this part as well so I could use some other source to get a good grasp of this!

Comment: Did you try the WP page on "geometric series"?

Comment: Google 'Cauchy product'. When you square the first sum, the n is left from the simplification of the inner sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $|x|<1$ then [Geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) says:
\begin{equation}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\dfrac{1}{1-x}\qquad (1)\end{equation}
In your case  substitute $n-1=s$ and then use it.

Derivating $(1)$ we get
\begin{align*}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}&=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\ \iff\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}&=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} \end{align*}

Now multiply by $x$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Derivate again

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^{k-1}=-\dfrac{x+1}{(x-1)^3}$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of headaches! :D

Comment: @Spiritios No problem :P remember the first formula that if $|x|<1$ then $\sum_k x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ the other can always be derivated from this one and is also a good exercise :D