# How to find sum of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(\frac{7}{8})^{k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do we compute the following infinite series?
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(\frac{7}{8})^{k-1}$

It arises as part of a more general problem. What is the expectations of the number of draw srequired from a uniform [0,1] distribution before you get a number that is $\epsilon$ close to 1?

Intuitively, it is $1/\epsilon$, but to show this, you would need to calculate the expectation:
$E[X] = \sum_X f(X)\cdot X = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k(\frac{7}{8})^{k-1}$

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/894998/42969

Comment: Search tip: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series?tab=Frequent

Answer (score 1):

The thing to notice is that this looks a lot like a derivative.

Let $p\in(0,1)$. Then $kp^{k-1} = \frac{d}{dp}p^{k}$

So that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp^{k-1} = \frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p^{k} = \frac{d}{dp}\frac{p}{1-p}$

It's now a case of some elementary differentiation and plugging in the required value of $p$